# Piping raw PCM stream into libsndfile

Tags: pipe, pcm, libsndfile

I'm working on a application, and I'd like to pipe a raw PCM stream from one application into mine. I'm thinking the stream needs to be opened with libsndfile using the [sf_open_virtual](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#open_virtual) function, but I can't quite figure out the exact process. Any help with this would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured this one out. You can pipe raw PCM into your app with a simple Unix pipe like this:

`firstapp | libsndfileapp -`